# Unable to compare regular expression with string properly

Tags: regex, linux, bash

Basically im trying to add up all the numbers in a file called numbers.txt . It contains non-number strings as well .
Here is my shell script

```
#!/bin/bash
sum=0
x=$(cat numbers.txt)
re='^[0-9]+$'
for i in $x
 do
    echo $i
    if [ $i = re ]
     then
      sum=`expr $sum + $i`
    fi
done
echo $sum
```

Here is the Output

```
abc
hellow
123
1
2
3
hello67
39
0
```

Below is txt file

```
abc hellow 123
1 2 3
hello67 39
```

The output instead of zero should have been 168 .

Answer (score 2):

Corrected your script a little, for comparing with regex i use `=~`:

```
#!/bin/bash
sum=0
x=$(cat numbers.txt)
re='^[0-9]+$'
for i in $x
 do
    echo $i
    if [[ $i =~ $re ]]
     then
      sum=$((sum + i))
    fi
done
echo $sum
```

Comment: `$[...]` is so deprecated that the manual doesn't even mention its existence any longer – the modern replacement is `sum=$((sum + i))` (or `((sum += i))`)

Comment: Thanks, agree with you

Comment: Thanks for the answer ! By the way , no need to put semi colon after if , as then is in the next line .

Answer (score 1):

You are literally comparing the strings, not matching a regex.
You can use `grep` for regex matching, for example:

```
#!/bin/bash
sum=0
x=$(cat numbers.txt)
re='^[0-9]+$'
for i in $x
do
  echo $i
  echo $i | grep -oP "${re}" &> /dev/null
  if [ $? == "0" ]
  then
    sum=`expr $sum + $i`
  fi
done
echo $sum
```

`echo $i | grep -oP "${re}"` will pipe the text into `grep`. If it matches the regex, `grep` returns `0` which will be written into the special variable `$?`. So if that is `0`, you know you have a number and can sum it up. That is the reason for `if [ $? == "0" ]`.

<s>Btw: `=` will assign a value to a variable, to compare, you need to use `==`.</s>
When using `[` it actually does, my bad.

Comment: `= will assign a value to a variable` this is not true for `[`, a single `=` will compare strings for equality, see `man [`. I think OP was looking for `[[ $i =~ $re ]]`

Comment: `if [ $? == "0" ]` isn't necessary. `if grep -qE "$re" <<< "$i"; then ((sum += i)); fi` would accomplish the task of updating the `sum` when the field is a non-negative integer number. But the external `grep` call isn't required at all. Using the `=~` operator should be more efficient than calling an external command: `[[ $i =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]] && ((sum += i))`

Comment: Agreed , `=~` would be better than using `grep`. And sure, your solution is quite a lot shorter, but imho it is a good idea not to make it too hard for a beginner to understand the solution you propose.